# How to have Jquery blur trigger on everything except hyperlinks/input buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a slight issue getting a jquery action to function ideally.    Currently everything is working properly on a blur from a particular field, which is called "person_email".  The issue is that if the end user does this, and decides to click a hyperlink for example on the rest of the page that jquery from the blur triggers, the user see's this briefly, and then continues to the corresponding link.

Ideally this would work that the blur would only trigger if a hyperlink was not clicked.

```
var $email = $("#person_email");
var $hint = $("#hint_edit");

$email.on('blur',function() {
  $hint.hide; // Hide the hint
  $(this).mailcheck({
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
        // First error - Fill in/show entire hint element
        var suggestion = "Did you mean: <span class='suggestion'>" +
                         "<span class='address'>" + "</span>" +
                         "<a href='#' class='domain'>" + suggestion.address +
                         "@" + suggestion.domain + "</a></span>?";

        $hint.html(suggestion).fadeIn(150);
    }
  });
});

 $hint.on('click', '.domain', function() {
  // On click, fill in the field with the suggestion and remove the hint
  $email.val($(".suggestion").text());
  $hint.fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(this).empty();
  });
  return false;
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("a").on("click",function() {
  $email.off();
});
```